# How to use pyinstaller to pack a local Python package?

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I found a PIP package whose source code I modified to make it work better. I would like to pack this package, which can be installed through its setup.py file, with my script into one executable using pyInstaller. But I don't know how. Is this even possible, or am I stuck with the PIP version? Thanks.

Comment: Install the package with your modifications. PyInstaller packs your installed version into the executable.

Comment: Interesting. I thought PyInstaller looks at the source code and grabs the packages from PyPI. But actually it's just packing what is installed on my computer? That's pretty cool! Thanks a lot, today I learned something new.